# Binomial distribution approximated by normal distribution: How to arrive at this identity?

Tags: stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, stochastic-calculus, binomial-distribution

This question regards a paper by Zurek, Cucchietti and Paz from 2008 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.quant-ph/0611200), in specific how to arrive at (12) from (10) and (11). This seems to be straight forward math, but I don't get it. I will summarize what is written in the paper:

> Equation (10) gives the so called decoherence factor for a special "simple"
> model, that the authors use:
>
> $$r(t)=\sum_{l=0}^N {N\choose
> l}|\alpha|^{2(N-l)}|\beta|^{2l}e^{ig(N-2l)t}\tag{10}$$
>
> Where $|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2=1$ and both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are
> complex numbers.
>
> Equation (11) gives the Gaussian approximation of the factor
>
> $${N\choose l}|\alpha|^{2(N-l)}|\beta|^{2l}\approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi
> N|\alpha\beta|^2}}e^{-\frac{(l-N|\beta|^2)^2}{2N|\alpha\beta|^2}}\tag{11}$$
>
> This (according to the authors) immediately yields the result, given
> in equation (12):
>
> $$|r(t)|=e^{-2N|\alpha\beta|^2(gt)^2}\tag{12}$$.

Substituting (11) in (10) and taking the absolute value doesn't seem to do it. Somehow (by arriving at (12)) there have been made several steps I seem to not fully understand. Can anyone explain to me what is happening here?

Comment: FYI you're missing a square root in (11)

Comment: Thank you. I corrected that.

Answer (score 3):

If $X \sim \text{Binomial}(N, |\beta|^2)$, then $r(t)$ is $\mathbb{E}[e^{ig(N-2X)t}] = e^{igNt} \mathbb{E}[e^{-2igtX}]$.

The normal approximation approximates this Binomial distribution with $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ where $\mu = N|\beta|^2$ and $\sigma^2 = N|\alpha \beta|^2$. For the rest of this answer, assume $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$.

The characteristic function of $X$ is $\mathbb{E}[e^{iuX}] = e^{i \mu u - \sigma^2 u^2 / 2}$.
Plugging in the expressions for $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$  and plugging in $u = -2gt$, we have $\mathbb{E}[e^{-2igtX}] = e^{-2igt N|\beta|^2 - 2N |\alpha \beta|^2 (gt)^2}$.

Putting the pieces together, we have

$$|r(t)| = \left|e^{igNt} \mathbb{E}[e^{-2igt X}]\right|
= \left|\mathbb{E}[e^{-2igt X}]\right|
= \left|e^{-2igt N|\beta|^2 - 2N |\alpha \beta|^2 (gt)^2}\right|
= e^{- 2N |\alpha \beta|^2 (gt)^2}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Is that the way it is meant in the source I gave as well? Seems like I would never have gotten to what you explained from that.

Comment: To be more precise: Is there also a way that includes using (11) directly (as the authors seem to do)

Comment: @manuel459 If $f(l)$ denotes the right-hand side of (11), then they are approximating (10) with $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) e^{ig(N-2x)t} \, dx$.

Comment: Thank you. I have never seen that formula before. Is there a book (also on the calculations in your answer) that you could suggest me reading? Thank you.

Comment: @manuel459 Any undergraduate probability textbook (Ross "Probability Models," Pitman, etc.) should have these concepts: [normal approximation for the binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation), [expectation of a random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Definition), [LOTUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician)